# View Hierarchy not showing on XCode 13

Tags: ios, interface-builder, xcode13, view-hierarchy

I recently updated Xcode to Xcode 13.
I opened an old project and tried to edit a xib file with interface builder.
I can't figure out how to show the view hierarchy that used to be on the left on IB.
I have 2 views, but when I try to click on them it doesn't show its subviews. Am i doing something wrong or is it a bug ?

[image: Image of my Interface Builder. Clicking on a view in the left pane doesn't show its subviews.]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Click the Show/Hide Document Outline button:

[image]

[image]

Comment: That was so simple ! Thanks a lot